# What is the purpose of a raw pointer to unique_ptr function parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Skimming through the TensorFlow C++ API I stumbled upon a strange function signature:

```
Status Create(
     const FileSystemStoragePathSourceConfig & config,
     std::unique_ptr< FileSystemStoragePathSource > *result
)
```

I don't understand why `result` is a raw pointer to `unique_ptr`. Because usually when we want to pass `unique_ptr` as a function parameter we do it either by means of move (`&&`) or by reference `&` or by value. I haven't seen the use case of a raw pointer to `unique_ptr` before.

Comment: Wild guess, because the person(s) that wrote it prefer to manage out-parameters as by-address rather than by-reference, where the calling syntax can easily be misconstrued.

Comment: Also, it allows the output parameter to be optional. Something one could only do with pointers before `std::optional`.

Comment: "by value &" You might want to rephrase that. By ref is not by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TensorFlow is made by Google. [Google's C++ style guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments) says:

> All parameters passed by reference must be labeled `const`.

The implication of this is that all output parameters must be pointers, not references. This style isn't idiomatic C++ (the standard library passes output parameters by reference), but proponents of Google's style guide argue that passing output parameters as pointers makes it clearer which parameters are input and which are outputs.